# Using ImportExcel Chart functions doesn't display Series Header correctly

Tags: excel, powershell, import

I am using the importexcel module and have found a wierd behaviour. If I execute the below script

```
Install-Module -Name ImportExcel -Force
```

Everything installs clean etc.
Then I have created this really small script.

```
$array = ConvertFrom-Csv @"
Date,A,B,C
2016-04-02,20,25,15
2016-04-03,25,45,10
2016-04-04,15,29,25
"@
$fn = "c:\TEMP\trend.xlsx"
$c = New-ExcelChartDefinition -Title "Errors" `
    -ChartType LineMarkers `
    -XRange "AdUser[Date]" `
    -YRange  "AdUser[A]", "AdUSer[B]","AdUSer[C]" `
    -SeriesHeader "A","B","C"
$array | Export-Excel -Path $fn -AutoSize -TableName AdUser -ExcelChartDefinition $c -Show
```

However, when the spreadsheet opens it shows "Series 1", "Series 1", "Series 1" as the SeriesHeader instead of the expected "A","B","C".

While Excel is open if I delete or add any data row to the table, it refreshes the chart and displays the proper series header. Am I using this part wrong or is this a bug? Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Looks like an issue when specifying more than two items in `-SeriesHeader` Please open an issue on the ImportExcel GitHub repo, and add your example that demos the issue.

https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel/issues

Thanks
Doug

Comment: Submit to github as https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel/issues/841